# Как в фон добавить поперечную линию с заданной позицией и цветом?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Возник интересный вопрос: есть контейнер высотой 80 пикселей, залитый сплошным цветом. В этом контейнере есть рисунок высотой 70 пикселей и выровненный поверху, то есть остается еще внизу 10 пикселей.

Задача: добавить полосу шириной 1 пиксель другого цвета (#fff) на позиции 75 пикселя, чтобы получилась черта подчеркивания.

Можно реализовать это вставкой изображения размером в пиксель и "репитом" по оси, но хотелось бы сделать это средствами CSS на более "низком" уровне.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  background: #000 ;
}
```

```html
<html>  
  <body>  
    <div id="container">  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил его вот так: имею ширину 80, нужна линия толщиной 1 (внизу), с отступом от верха 76 и с отступом снизу (80 - 76 = 4) 4 пикселя, то есть остается - 4 пикселя, после белой полосы. Проверяем, 75 (черная) + 1 (белая) + 4 (опять черная)... догадались? Именно!

Я разделил свою полосу на три части, одну - 75, вторую - 1, третью - 4, теперь дело техники:

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: #fff;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 75px;
    background: #000 ;
}
#container1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 1px;
    background: #fff ;
}
#container2 {
    position: relative;
    height: 4px;
    background: #000 ;
}
#container img {
    border-bottom: 1px ;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}
</style>

<body>  
    <div id="container">
        <img src="x_c98331bf.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="container1"></div>
    <div id="container2"></div>
</body>
```

Осталось добавить рисунок.

Comment: Чего-то не получается код нормально вставить

Comment: @tukan Чтобы вставить код, нужно выделить его мышкой и нажать на кнопку 101010 или в любом удобном редакторе добавить уровень идентации в четыре пробела.

Comment: Что-то слишком много контейнеров на странице для решения этой задачи. Один можно точно грохнуть, а из второго сделать линию с абсолютным позиционированием сверху на 76px. Только все равно мое решение проще :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

    <style>
    body {
        background-color: #999;
    }

    #container {
        position: relative;
        height: 80px;
        background: #000 ;
    }

    #container img {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        height: 70px;
        width: 70px;
    }
    </style> 
    <body>  
    <div id="container">  
    <img src="x_c98331bf.jpg">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Белая полоса оказывается под черным фоном.

Comment: Вот теперь проверил :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#container {
position: relative;
    height: 80px;
    background: #000 ;
}
hr
{
    color: red;
    height:1px;
    margin:0px;
    margin-top:4px;
    padding:0px;    
}
img
{
    height:70px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
}
</style>

<html> 
    <body>  
    <div id="container">  
    <img src=""/>
    <hr>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Нет, не то! Про тег hr. Я знаю, тут надо именно пикселями.